# Does an update of my App clears my Apps SQLite Database?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite, cordova

I have an iOS app which uses an SQLite database. Sometimes I publish updates of my app.

What happens with the data in the SQLite database of my app? Will the SQLite database be reseted, i.e., reinitialized? Does the SQLite database remains unchanged and also the data until I change something manually?

Edit: I use PhoneGap to create my iOS app and the following SQLite plugin to generate the SQLite database: https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin The iOS code to generate the SQLite database is here: https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin/tree/master/src/ios

Comment: Is the database (file) in your app bundle or created (or copied) on first run and put in the documents folder? If it's the first, it's overwritten.

Comment: Adding to @MarcusAdams comment, ...else it isn't overwritten, nor is any data lost.  If you've changed your schema in the new app version, you should be aware of Core Data Model Versioning and Migration Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html

Comment: Agreed, and Core Data is a different matter entirely, which wasn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Please see my edit. I hope it helps you.

Comment: @CSmith Please see my edit. I hope it helps you.

Comment: no, it doesn't clear the database on app updates

Comment: @jcesarmobile What do I have to do if I want to update the database on update?

Comment: I haven't used the plugin, not sure if it provides a way to update the database or you have to do it as any other sqlite database (with alter table)

Comment: @jcesarmobile So I have to create the tables (create if not exist) in the first version and in the second version I apply create if not exist and alter table. Is this correct?

Comment: The second version should have a create if not exist for new users, with the new changes, and alter table if table exists to add the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its clear your SQLite Database completely. I already done it before using this cordova plugin, it wipe all my data. https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

Comment: Is there a way that the data will not be deleted?

Comment: Nope, there are no other way your data will be persistent.

Comment: Is this due to the plugin?

Comment: This means that I do not have to do alter table on each version? I just do create table all the time right?

Comment: Nope, any apps will be same. Every time you update the app, your data will be lost in sqlite.

Comment: You need to create again the table.

Comment: If the sqlite data is cleared after each update how can I store user configurations which should not be lost after an update?

Comment: Save it in info.plist :)

Comment: I mean wenn the user uses the app and changes some settings. Where do I save them that they persist after updating the app?